# Error starting gnome-terminal from /etc/rc.local ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, rc, gnome-terminal, startupscript

```
I am unable to start gnome-terminal from rc.local , with the following error.

** (gnome-terminal:1304): WARNING **: Command line `dbus-launch --autolaunch=bd53fdd726adb41172f458c100000007 --binary-syntax --close-stderr' exited with non-zero exit status 1: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.\n
Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display: 
Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display:

the command inside rc.local is
cd /path/to/server
gnome-terminal -e 'sudo node startserver.js'
```

Comment: It works fine if i manually start it via sudo /etc/rc.local

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be an error message trying to tell you something: `exited with non-zero exit status 1: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed`- in other words, rc.local doesn't have an X display to start gnome-terminal from.

If you're sure that an X display will be available at the time this executes (and I doubt this - rc.local finishes executing long before an X display comes up), you can try `env DISPLAY=:0 gnome-terminal -e 'sudo node startserver.js'`. This may be problematic, as the `gnome-terminal` will run as root (which is a Bad Idea for several reasons).

If, on the other hand, you're trying to start a terminal in the logged-in user's X display (which *seems* to be your end goal), you may want to add the command to your autostart scripts. See [this](http://www.ubuntuka.com/autostart-ubuntu-startup/) for the GUI version, see your `~/.config/autostart` and `/etc/xdg/autostart` for the results.

Comment: thanks but my server listens on port 80 it needs sudo to bind to that port.

Comment: @techgentsia: How is that related to my answer? I'm **not** suggesting to change what runs *inside* gnome-terminal (which is your `sudo whatever`, this **stays the same**), but the user of the `gnome-terminal` process itself.

Comment: I tried to run gnome-terminal inside rc.local because it starts with root privilege. is there no way to do so...